Enable Background Processing in iOS Flutter app
I am developing a timer app in iOS using Flutter. User can also choose to run the timer with background music.
When I run the app on debug mode by connecting a physical device, the app (timer) works when the screen is locked or app is in background.
However, on actual launch - it did not work the same way, i.e. timer did not update when the app was on background/screen locked. Interestingly, when the music is enabled by the user, timer updates correctly even in background.

What am I missing here? Will enabling "background processing" solve the issue? This documentation talks about adding "task identifier" in Permitted background tasks array. Is it how it should be done? Should I use any flutter package to manage the same?
Here is my code for updating Timer:
import 'dart:async';

class TimerService {
  Timer? _timer;
  late Duration _duration;

  void startTimer(
      Duration duration, Function(Duration) onTick, Function onComplete) {
    _duration = duration;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (_duration.inSeconds == 0) {
        _timer?.cancel();
        onComplete();
      } else {
        _duration -= const Duration(seconds: 1);
        onTick(_duration);
      }
    });
  }

  void stopTimer() {
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  Duration get duration => _duration;
}


You don't need an active timer to track elapsed time. You simply record the start date of the timer and compute elapsed time since then. You can use a timer to periodically update your UI but you don't need to do that when your app is not onscreen.

Also, subtracting a second from a value every second will not be accurate. If you need to inform the user that a timer has ended when your app is in the background then you should schedule a local notification.
